# Check whether array is sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

Is there a way to avoid this error when sorting an array?

```
 ArgumentError: comparison of Hash with Hash failed
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
a.sort if a.is_sortable?
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.sort` without confirming what data structure is?

Comment: You can use a `begin` `rescue` block to rescue from exceptions.

Comment: Try: `a.sort if a.respond_to?(:sort)`

Comment: @Phlip No... You try `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}].sort` :)

Comment: @Phlip Nope. The question isn't whether the array has the `sort` method. The question is how to validate that the contents of the array are sortable.

Comment: @ArupRakshit How do you confirm the data structure of the elements in an array?
The data structure can vary.

Comment: So you don't know the content of it.. From where the data is being produced?

Comment: If the same source sometimes gives `[2,3,1]` and sometimes `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]`... then fix the source first, so that it guarantees data structure..

Comment: @Phlip it doesn't work for `a = [{'aaa'=> 3, 'bbb' => 2},{'s'=>2, 'd'=>1}]`
`a.respond_to?(:sort)` is true but getting the error.

Comment: @ArupRakshit The content can vary. It can be hash, number, string, ... based on the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting is usually based on [`Comparable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Comparable.html):

> The `Comparable` mixin is used by classes whose objects may be ordered. The class must define the `<=>` operator, which compares the receiver against another object, returning -1, 0, or +1 depending on whether the receiver is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object.

so you could look at:

```
a.grep(Comparable)
```

and see if that has the same length as `a`. Or you could say:

```
a.all? { |e| e.is_a? Comparable }
```

But you really don't need all of `Comparable` for `#sort` to work, you just need a `<=>` method so you could say:

```
a.all? { |e| e.respond_to? :<=> }
```

Of course, all the above assumes that all the elements of `a` are that same as far as `<=>` is concerned (i.e. `x <=> y` works for any two entries `x` and `y` of `a`) and that's not necessarily the case even if all elements of `a` are `Comparable`s or even if they all respond to `<=>`. We're also assuming that `<=>` is implemented correctly but if you have a bad implementation of the spaceship operator then all bets are off anyway.

For an arbitrary array `a`, the only way to tell if you can sort it is to try to sort it and see if it explodes. For arrays where you know a little more about the elements (i.e. the elements are all instances of the same class), you have some options.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, there is no `is_sortable?` method.

Long answer: `sort` uses the `<=>` operator, so you could check if it's defined:

```
a.sort if a.all? { |item| item.respond_to?(:<=>) }
```

However it is defined for hashes because they inherit from `Kernel`:

```
{}.respond_to?(:<=>) # => true
{}.method(:<=>) # => #<Method: Hash(Kernel)#<=>>
```

But, when you try to use it on hashes, you usually get back `nil`, which causes the exception:

```
# No idea why this should work:
{} <=> {} # => 0
{a: :b} <=> {c: :d} # => nil
```

So, probably best if you use `sort_by` instead and come up with your own sorting algorithm that can handle hashes.

Comment: Checking `Comparable` might be safer but yeah, try it and watch it explode is about all you have.